# {small_file_url} calling my thunb

Tags: templates, thumbnails

When expression engine is creating a small file it is putting them in a folder call "thumb". How do I call that file from a template to render on the finished page?

{m_topic_img} calls my full image but how do i customize {small_file_url} from the EE docs to call the correct file? I am using GD2 to generate the thumbs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating different sizes of your images you need to use the following tag to output them on the fronted in a channel entries tag

```
{image_field:size_short_name}
```

So in your example this should work:

```
{m_topic_img:small}
```